# JSON has extra formatting, specified name/value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My code looks a little like this:

```
var data = $(this).serializeArray(data);

$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

I run a `console.log` as well and I see the JSON string formatted as:

`[{"name":"inputName", "value":"inputValue"}]`

Whereas I'm expecting:

`[{"inputName":"inputValue"}]`

Am I misunderstanding JSON formatting or is there a way to get this to format properly?

Comment: `serializeArray` doesn't take any argument

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand, buy you should just run `JSON.stringify(data)` without serializing the array first.

Comment: Sorry Joy, that was a typo. Francisc, I'm calling that because I'm getting all the data on submit of a form (without specifying the form fields). Is there a way I can get all that data without `serializeArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON (well, any hash/dict) is formatted as `{ property : value }` (or `{ key : value }`). If you want each of the `value` well...values! in an array, you can do so with a simple `for..in` statement.

```
vals = [];
hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
for (item in hash) {
    vals.append(hash[item]);
}

console.log(vals);  // => [1, 2, 3]
```

But to directly your answer, you will never see `[{"inputName":"inputValue"}]` because `inputName` is not a key, but a variable (just like `inputValu`e)

Answer (score 0):

The formatting is correct, as described inside the docs: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: The formatting is correct for that method, right? But is the alternate formatting incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

[$.serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) produces arrays like that.

You can modify the output from `$.serializeArray` to build a array like you want using [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var customArray = $.map(data,function(obj,i){
    var temp  = {};
    temp[obj.name] = obj.value;        
    return temp;
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/u86Eu/)